# Invalid Parameter in source dir using robocopy

Tags: batch-file, directory, robocopy

I am using robocopy to copy from one directory to another.

I have tested the code using miscellaneous source directories but I get an error when executing  one particular directory:

```
set "source=C:\Program Files (x86)\Phoresis\Backup"
```

I get the error:

> Invalid paramter 3 "(x86)\Phoresis\Backup"

Have tried using single quotes and have wrapped the variable assignments in "" as there are spaces in the directory paths.

Code:

```
set "newDirectory=F:\Cap2 Flex Backup"

REM Timesatmp a new folder
set "DirName=%date:~-4,4%.%date:~-7,2%.%date:~0,2%.%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%
MD \%newDirectory%"

set "source=C:\Program Files (x86)\Phoresis\Backup"

robocopy %source% %DirName% /e /z /Mir
```

Struggling to get my head around spaces/special characters in vb scripts/batch so any input appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: 1. change your `robocopy` command line to `robocopy "%source%" "%DirName%" /e /z /Mir`; 2. what is the `MD` command line for? ; you create a directory but `robocopy` does not use it; and there is a leading `\\`` which should be replaced by `"`;

Comment: Ok will try, why do I need qoutes surrounding these variables,?

Comment: Because the stored paths contain spaces, which are interpreted as argument separators, unless an argument is enclosed in `""`...

Comment: Does wrapping the variable with "" at declaration not do this

Comment: No; `set "VAR=a string"` assigns `a string` to variable `VAR`, without any quotes; the quotes just avoid problems with special characters like `&`, `^`, `(`, `)`, _SPACE_,...; if no such characters appear, it is the same as `set VAR=a string`; so the quoted version is safe whereas the unquoted one isn't; but when expanding (reading) a variable, you have to take care of such characters again; in your case, without the surrounding quotes, the _SPACE_ is interpreted as argument separator, so `C:\Program`, `Files` and `(x86)\Phoresis\Backup` are three arguments;

Comment: Thanks very useful info I will use in Future- will modify code and update u

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do with the `MD` command; should it create the destination root directory, which contains then the timestamp folder of `DirName`? once I got the intention, I'll post an answer with all the information...

Comment: Yes that's correct the idea is to create a new directory containing a time stamped folder (DirName) every time the code executes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue in your code is, that there are no quotes `""` around the source and destination directories in the `robocopy` command line. Since they contain spaces, such are interpreted as argument separators; so `%source%`, which is expanded to the value `C:\Program Files (x86)\Phoresis\Backup`, will be interpreted as three arguments `C:\Program`, `Files` and `(x86)\Phoresis\Backup`. To avoid that, put `""` around the path arguments like `"%source%"`.

Here is the fixed code:

```
set "newDirectory=F:\Cap2 Flex Backup"
md "%newDirectory%"

rem Timesatmp a new folder
set "DirName=%newDirectory%\%date:~-4,4%.%date:~-7,2%.%date:~0,2%.%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%"

set "source=C:\Program Files (x86)\Phoresis\Backup"

robocopy "%source%" "%DirName%" /e /z /Mir
```

Additional issues/notes:

- although you used quotes in your `set` command lines, which avoid troubles with some special characters (`&`, `^`, `(`, `)`, <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, etc.), the `""` are not part of the values stored in the variables; so when expanding (reading) the variables, you need to take care of such special characters once again, by surrounding the read variable by `""`;
- the `md` command has been fixed (there was a leading `\`, but no opening `"`) and moved up;
- variable `DirName` contains now also the parent (root) destination directory `F:\Cap2 Flex Backup`, which is stored in variable `newDirectory`, to avoid relative paths for `robocopy`; since `source` contains an absolute path too, the script can be located and executed anywhere;
- regard that the timestamp retrieved by `%date%` and `%time%` depend on the locale and region settings of the system; therefore this script is not quite portable; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203116/5047996) to overcome that;

Comment: Very helpful thanks. One question- (I did note the batch had to be executed in the destination directory to work correctly so something to do with relative paths?)- can u expand  on point 3 ?

Comment: You're welcome! yes, I used absolute paths for both source and destination, so the batch file can be located and executed anywhere...